# Android Tensorflow : Conversion from Keras model into tensorflow graph gives same prediction always

Tags: android, tensorflow

I converted Keras model into tensorflow graph to use in an android application. Conversion seems to be correct, I tested using python script in desktop. But when I execute inference in android, I always get same prediction for any input. I followed this [blog](http://blog.stratospark.com/creating-a-deep-learning-ios-app-with-keras-and-tensorflow.html) for conversion.

The model is trained using batch normalization. Should I need to configure anything in android interface for prediction. I am not getting exception in android application, but getting same prediction always.

Comment: Can you confirm that another model (like a standard Inception or the one from the tutorial) is working with your code? If that does work, are you able to run a C++ example on the desktop and get the right results with your model?

Comment: Thanks for your response. Other model is working fine with my code. I was able to run python script to check whether my model works , below is the snippet of that with: 
    
with open('graph.pb', "rb") as f:    
    optimized_graph.ParseFromString(f.read())
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(optimized_graph, name="")

x = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('input:0')
y = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('output:0')
......
print (sess.run(y, feed_dict={x:xTest}))

Comment: did you find a solution to include your keras model with batch normalization in an Android app?